# Statically Link Executables with OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I'm trying to get OpenModelica to produce a statically linked executable.  I've created a `.mos` file and in that script I am calling `simulate(...)` of a model.  This produces an executable but it is dynamically linked.  I'd like to get a statically linked executable.

I've tried adding `--linkType static` when I invoke `omc` but that does nothing.  I looked in the `.makefile` produced as an artifact by the call to `simulate(...)` and I see this:

```
# define OMC_LDFLAGS_LINK_TYPE env variable to "static" to override this
OMC_LDFLAGS_LINK_TYPE=dynamic
```

This seems to imply that if I set the `OMC_LDFLAGS_LINK_TYPE` environment variable to `static` (before invoking `omc`?) that it will somehow cause static linking.  But that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions on how I can get `omc` (when running a script) to generate statically linked executables on Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: Nah, this doesn't really work in Linux as we do not build the simulation runtime as a static library anymore. I don't know who took this decision. In windows we build the static versions as well.

Comment: It seems the only way to fix this is to compile OpenModelica from scratch and build static versions of the dependent libraries.